# Best to isolate the database in multiple instances?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I read on a forum about the use of database isolated environments are neccessary for any large project that handles "big" data. For instance I will be using the following table for ALL blogs:

```
projectname_blog_blogposts
```

We all know that the table will be very big. Probably hard to maintain, maybe awful situation if the table is corrupt or something like that. I don't know, I don't have any experience to confirm such a statement.

**So instead of doing that. Is this approach better:**

```
projectname_blog_1_blogposts
projectname_blog_2_blogposts
projectname_blog_3_blogposts
```

And then split them up like this:

**DATABASE01**

```
projectname_blog_1_blogposts
```

**DATABASE02**

```
projectname_blog_2_blogposts
```

**DATABASE03**

```
projectname_blog_3_blogposts
```

Sorry if the question is fuzzy. But I do hope you guys understand me.

Where can I read more about this so I can make a good choice?

Comment: "Large" = what?  If you are talking about gigabytes, that is not "large".  Terabytes is "large".  "Multi-tenancy" involved extra hassles, extra overhead, etc.; don't do it for "small" projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are facing can be likened to the problem of multitenancy as you are talking about multiple applications (multiple blog) and one or more tables, schemas, databases, instances. A good starting point can be the following article from MSDN: [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). The article is focused on Microsoft SQL Server but it can be easily generalized.

Regards
Giovanni

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Giovanni!